Federal withholding
My W4 is filled out correctly, Exempt is not marked. Federal taxes are not being withheld. Why is that? I file head of household, 1 dependent under 18 and no additional taken out.

Ask the employer?

Are any other taxes being withheld? Is this a partial check?

Yes other taxes are being taken out. I have asked the employer and they  said they havent changed anything to where federal would stop coming out. Wasnt much help. I just dont want to end up owing taxes and I cant figure out why they are no longer coming out. No its not a partial check.

@Aretha  you said in a comment "they havent changed anything to where federal would stop coming out."  does that mean you had checks this year where they did take out federal tax? did you change the form recently?

looks like one or two paychecks it did. But i havent changed anything on my w4

What is your expected annual pay? If you are expected to make under or close to the standard deduction, they would not withhold any taxes since you won't owe anything (for federal).
For example if you are filing Head of Household your standard deduction is $21,900 for 2024. If you are only expected to make $20k for the year, then you would owe no taxes when you file.
If you want to be sure what your tax obligation will be (and your pay is consistent throughout the year) you can use the IRS W4 calculator.

To be clear, if this is a new job what matters is not what the pay will actually be for the time worked this year, but what the pay would be if the job (or any equal-paying one) was held for the full year. And with the $2000 CTC this asker can actually make up to almost $42k-per-year and have zero expected net income tax liability and thus zero income tax withholding.
